# Please identify this vintage bike - peculiar frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, women-specific

Helping out a friend to identify this bike, it's got quite an interesting frame and is located northern nsw, Australia. Haven't been able to see a name or printing on it. It has 3 blue stars down the front under the Handle bars. If anyone knows or has seen a bike like this, am keen to work out it origins. Thanks[image][image]

Comment: I can't say that I've ever seen anything like it.  Unfortunately missing detail, but appears to be a pretty old bike (40-50 years old) with a standard (for the time) coaster brake.  There likely is a brand name ("Bendix", "New Departure", et al) stamped on the brake arm (coming off the rear axle and bolted to the chain stay).  This brand might give some hint as to the bike's ancestry.

Comment: Australian stuff tends to be a lot more regionalised than other markets.  Malvern, Malvern Star, and Southern Star are common Aussie bike brands.

Comment: Beautiful frame! You are sure to get looks on the street if you end up restoring it.

Answer (score 3):

The three stars are the logo for "Malvern Star" which is an Australian brand that has been operating since 1902.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvern_Star

http://www.malvernstar.com.au/